# How does gcc evaluate fraction over fraction?

Tags: c

How will an expression of the form `a/b/c/d` be evaluated in gcc ? Will it be `(a*d) / (b*c)`  or will it be `(  ( (a/b) / c) / d )` ? Is there a rule for this in C standard ?

Comment: also there are rules, they are important...

Comment: i tried on two different compilers, observed anomaly and hence the question arises, definitely not playing trivia here. I was expecting the downvoting.

Comment: See the precedence table.

Comment: @Bleamer What anomaly? Since it is defined by the standard to be `((a/b)/c)/d`, I'm curious what compiler breaks it in which way.

Comment: had a 16 bit compiler, not able to derive name, but tried this on dos 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

order of operations:

a/b/c/d is just like it says: ((a/b)/c)/d

Answer (score 3):

The C standard (and the C++ standard) says that operators are evaluated from left to right once priority is decided. The compiler MAY optimize the operations if it knows this can be done without affecting the actual result, but it would be invalid if the result [within the defined behaviour of the standard] is affected in such a way that it alters the result. In particular, you can expect small constants to be optimized into something larger, if ALL the values are known at compilation time.

In other words, ((a/b)/c)/d should be calculated.

--
Mats

Comment: Especially, an alternation may affect the result if you have overflows. So doing a/c*b instead of a*b/c might prevent overflow, but induce inaccuracy.

Comment: @glglgl There are all manner of different ways that the result may be "changed" if the compiler decides to alter the order and/or the way the value is calculated. But at the same time, if the compiler can determine that it IS safe to perform such an optimization, it can do so, which is my point.

Comment: My point was that it can be up to the user to change thinks if it sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplicative operators are all left-associative, as given by the syntax ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

> **6.5.5 Multiplicative operators**
> **Syntax**
> 1
>
> ```
> multiplicative-expression:
>         cast-expression
>         multiplicative-expression * cast-expression
>         multiplicative-expression / cast-expression
>         multiplicative-expression % cast-expression
> ```

so it will be parsed as

```
((a / b) / c) / d
```